Form (post) not pass value of input type file
I have a problem with a form.
All variables in post are passed, except the image.
If I use "enctype="multipart/form-data" the file is uploaded to the folder but the value of input (file name) is not passed in post. However, if I delete enctype="multipart/form-data" I am given the value of input (file name) but it is not uploaded to the folder. I tried with firefox, chrome and edge thinking it was a cache problem, but nothing. In php.ini max_post_size is 128 mb. I have php 7. Thanks to anyone who can help me.

The filename will be in $_FILES['xxx']['name'] where xxx is the name of the input element. All the information about uploaded files is in $_FILES, not $_POST.

See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php-files

In upload.php the variable $immagine = $_POST['immagine']; is empty. immagine is the name of input. It should contain the name of file (01.jpg for example). It contain 01.jpg only if i remove "enctype="multipart/form-data" from form.

Thank you, I understand. I was wrong to want to insert $image ($image=$_POST['image']) into the db. I need to enter $_FILES['image']['name']. That's how it works. Thank you very much.
